# tmux scrollback buffer limited to current screen - scrolling doesn't show previous actions' output

Tags: terminal, tmux

After upgrading to El Capitan, my `tmux` scrollback buffer is limited to a single screen. If I scroll up, I can see output from Mac `Terminal`, but all `tmux` output is truncated.

In the screenshot, you can see that instead of the expected display of me `ls`-ing, it shows me calling `tmux` - the last thing I did in OSX `Terminal`.

I have `set -g history-limit 100000` in my `tmux.conf`, but that file hasn’t changed from Yosemite to El Capitan.

[image: Truncated ls output, with tmux call]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `echo $TERM` revealed that paging was still handled by `screen`, I created `~/.screenrc` and inserted `termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@`. This allowed scrolling as desired.

Comment: what does this do?  I'm having a similar issue where when I change tmux's history size it seems to be capped at around 9000 after a certain point.  I'm using gnome-terminal not xterm (unsure if that is relevent)